# Why does having a USB to Ethernet Adapter plugged in prevent primary adapter from receiving DHCP address?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager, netplan

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6 on a Jetson Nano

On boot, I'm trying to have 2 network adapters configured like so:

eth0: DHCP 10.120.0.0/24

eth1: Static set to 192.168.1.10 (USB to Ethernet Adapter)

Currently, **if I boot with the USB network adapter plugged in** I do not get a DHCP address for eth0.  But I do get a static IP 192.168.1.10 for eth1.

**If I boot without the USB adapter plugged in**, I get an address for eth0 via DHCP just fine

I can get my configuration working only if I boot without the USB adapter to get DHCP on eth0 and then If I plug it in after boot, I get my static IP 192.168.1.10

netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true

    eth1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.10/24
```

Comment: Please post your network configuration file.

Comment: Posted, any ideas?  I think it has to do with the USB to ethernet adapter being a removable device

Comment: Could you check if the mac addresses stay the same for eth0 and eth1 after boot with the USB adapter plugged in and when not plugged in?